# Is it a problem to have non homogeneus sampling time in Bayes Filter?

Tags: nonparametric-bayes, particle-filter

I have a doubt related with Recursive State Estimation using Bayes Filter (actually using an aproximation to that through Particle Filters)

This algorithm is explained in several sources with sampling every $\Delta t$, and assumes a fixed $\Delta t$.

My questions are:

- how to choose a $\Delta t$ that is good enough for the problem?
- Is is feasible to have a $\Delta t$ that is not homogenous, so let say we sample at $t=1$ then $t=3$  then $t=10$ etc?.